# .Net Core 6.0 C# How to process nested Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBEntry?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

How to process the following structure in DynamoDB column?

```
{"property1" {"N": 1}, "property2" {"N": 2}, "property3" {"N": 2}}
```

I have tried the following:

```
                            if (doc.ContainsKey("dimensions") && doc["dimensions"].GetType() != typeof(DynamoDBNull))
                            {
                                //JObject dimension = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(doc["dimensions"]);
                                var dimension = doc["dimensions"].ToJson();
                                if (dimension != null)
                                {
                                    if (decimal.TryParse((string)dimension["length"]["N"], out decimal length))
                                        product.Length = length;
                                    if (decimal.TryParse((string)dimension["width"]["N"], out decimal width))
                                        product.Width = width;
                                    if (decimal.TryParse((string)dimension["weight"]["N"], out decimal weight))
                                        product.Weight = weight;
                                    if (decimal.TryParse((string)dimension["height"]["N"], out decimal height))
                                        product.Height = height;
                                }
                            }
```

but bumnp into exception.

Comment: What do you mean by process, store?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-json.html

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Document`, then access the properties.